# d3.svg.line().x function not called

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to draw a line chart with price on the y axis and date on the x axis.

when executing:

```
.attr("d", function(d){
            console.log(line(d.closePrice));
            return line(d);
        });
```

line(d.closePrice) returns null and d3.svg.line().x() and d3.svg.line().y are never called. I have a similar working example which uses d3.scale.linear() and I can't figure out what is causing my code to fail.

```
    var x = d3.time.scale()
        .domain([new Date(closes[0].closeDate), new Date(closes[closes.length - 1].closeDate)])
        .range([margin, width - margin]);


    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([closePriceMin, closePriceMax])
        .range([height - margin, margin]);


    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) {
            console.log("line x called");
            return x(new Date(d.closeDate));
        })
        .y(function(d) {
            console.log("line y called");
            return y(d.closePrice);
        });


    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

    svg.attr("height", height)
        .attr("width", width);

    svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(closes)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")            
        .attr("d", function(d){
            console.log(line(d.closePrice));
            return line(d);
        });
```

I am getting the json from a file using:

```
d3.json("data.json", function(error, json){

    for(var close in json){
        closes.push(json[close]);
```

Json format:

```
[{
"id": 6031839,
"equityId": 52597,
"closeDate": "Apr 8, 2016",
"closePrice": 12.73,
"sma12Day": 13.891666666666664,
"sma26Day": 13.184230769230773,
"ema12Day": 12.533611111111112,
"ema26Day": 12.696952662721895,
"macd": -0.1633415516107828,
"macdSignal": -0.17577601845764257,
"macdHistogram": 0.012434466846859782,
"openPrice": 12.91,
"high": 12.91,
"low": 12.72,
"volume": 22700,
"closePeak": false,
"closeTroff": false,
"macdPeak": false,
"macdTroff": false
}, {
"id": 6030002,
"equityId": 52597,
"closeDate": "Apr 7, 2016",
"closePrice": 12.61,
"sma12Day": 13.908333333333331,
"sma26Day": 13.159615384615385,
"ema12Day": 12.385416666666666,
"ema26Day": 12.570059171597633,
"macd": -0.18464250493096657,
"macdSignal": -0.17599694807672042,
"macdHistogram": -0.008645556854246145,
"openPrice": 12.78,
"high": 12.78,
"low": 12.6,
"volume": 20700,
"closePeak": false,
"closeTroff": true,
"macdPeak": false,
"macdTroff": true
}]
```

Comment: Could u pls share the JSON or jsFiddle? So i can have a look

Comment: please see updates

Answer (score 0):

I check with the JSON data and i get to know your closeDate field is not current. Please have a look on the [date format](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Formatting.md). This will give you a whole idea about the date formatting.

I did the change in the JSON

```js
var data = [{"closePriceDate":"Apr-8-2016","closePrice":93.24},{"closePriceDate":"Apr-9-2016","closePrice":95.35}];

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 300 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatDate = d3.time.format("%b-%e-%Y");

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(formatDate.parse(d.closePriceDate)) ; })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.closePrice); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return formatDate.parse(d.closePriceDate); }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.closePrice; }));

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Price ($)");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```